# TWM: Bring xterm to front on clicking anywhere in the window

Tags: linux, window-manager, xterm, twm

Can someone tell me what should I put in my `.twmrc`, so that an xterm window is brought to front (raised) when I click anywhere in the window. Currently, I have to click on the title bar to bring it to front.

Presently, I don't have any `.twmrc` in my HOME folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like:

```
Button1 = : window : f.raise
Button1 = : title | frame : f.function "move-or-raise"
Function "move-or-raise" { f.move f.deltastop f.raise }
```

in your ~/.twmrc

See twm(1) under "BINDINGS".

Comment: I dont understand the syntax, but it works!

Comment: @maxelost: Could you please how can I see the twm(1) under bindings? Do you mean "man BINDINGS" (that doesnt work for me).

Comment: @maxelost : Actually, now, I am unable to move windows. Earlier, I was able to drag windows by clicking and holding on the title bar. Now it doesn't work :(

Comment: @JP19: I meant `man twm`, then scroll down to the BINDINGS section.

Comment: I expanded the suggestion to allow moving of the window. Untested, though.

Comment: it does work! now I understand the syntax.. thanks much